# Sending HTTP GET request using urllib

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to send HTTP **GET** request using urllib/urllib2 with some data.

If we set some value of data param in urllib2.urlopen(url, data) the request object is changed to send POST request instead of GET.

Is there any way to achieve this? Standard or Hack?

Code snippet,

```
import requests
import urllib
query = urllib.urlencode({'query':'["=", ["fact", "role"], "storage"]'})
# using request object
print 'Output 1.'
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8082/v3/nodes", data=query)
print response.json()
print
# using urllib object
print 'Output 2.'
resp =  urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8082/v3/nodes', data=query)
print resp.read()
```

Output:

```
Output 1. 
[{u'deactivated': None, u'facts_timestamp': u'2016-02-04T14:06:07.269Z', u'name': u'node_xx_11', u'report_timestamp': None, u'catalog_timestamp': u'2016-02-04T14:06:16.958Z'}, {u'deactivated': None, u'facts_timestamp': u'2016-02-04T14:06:05.865Z', u'name': u'node_xx_12', u'report_timestamp': None, u'catalog_timestamp': u'2016-02-04T14:06:13.614Z'}]

Output 2.
The POST method is not allowed for /v3/nodes
```

For the 
References I have gone through,

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_data

This is not the road block for me, as I am able to use requests module for sending the data with **GET** request type. Curiosity is the reason of this post.

Comment: Have you tried any code?  It would be helpful if you included your code in your question.

Comment: Added. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` parameter of `urlopen` is used to set the body of the request. GET requests cannot contain a body, as they should only be used to return a resource, which should only be defined by it's URL.

If you need to pass parameters, you can append them to the url, in your case :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlopen('http://localhost:8082/v3/nodes?{}'.format(query))
```

Comment: If the query string is already correctly formatted you can even just append it trivially like this:

urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8082/v3/nodes?' + query)

Was that really the problem you had? I thought the question was about why you could not use the data parameter for your GET requests?

Answer (score 1):

The data parameter is for POST only and you cannot send a body in a GET request, so if you want to specify parameters you have to pass them through the URL.

One easy way to build such an URL is through the help of [urllib.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). Take a look at the documentation for this function.